# Back up Mechanism for Azure NSG

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-stack, azure-nsg

I'm working on backing up the Azure Network Security for Azure Stack.

I have used Azure Powershell and using that module I am able to export the existing config in a CSV and re deploy the stuff using CSV exported. 
My question would this module work on the Azure Stack, if not I am looking for some assistance using Azure RM template to back the existing config.

Comment: since it works in azure it should work with azure stack, i'd probably use ARM Templates for that, though

Comment: can you please share any reference for ARM templatees. I am not familiar with them much

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-security-group-create and reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/2018-11-01/networksecuritygroups

Answer (score 1):

I would recommnd using Azure Resource Manager templates for this purpose. You can build json files that describe the NSG. Examples of templates with nsg can be found in the [quickstart gallery](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-nsg-dmz-in-vnet).

You can read [More about Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/)

Hope it helps.